# FPDFText_SetText change nothing

Tags: settext, pdfium

I can change the text of an pdf text object and pdfium function says "all is ok". But when i save the changed pdf doc no changes are visible. Something is missing and i dont know what.

```cpp
int co = FPDFPage_CountObjects(page);
for (int j = 0; j < co; ++j) {
  FPDF_PAGEOBJECT pobj = FPDFPage_GetObject(page, j);
  if (FPDFPageObj_GetType(pobj) == FPDF_PAGEOBJ_TEXT) {
    ...

    if (FPDFText_SetText(pobj, (FPDF_WIDESTRING)L"New Text")) {                                          
      std::cout << "#VAL1 was changed\n";                                    
      //FPDFPage_GenerateContent(page);                                      
    }
  }
}

...
FPDF_ClosePage(page);
...

FPDF_FILEWRITE_EX fw;
fw.pFile = fopen("C:\\work\\newpdf.pdf", "wb");
fw.version = 1;
fw.WriteBlock = MyDelegateSaveFunc;

FPDF_SaveAsCopy(doc, &fw, FPDF_NO_INCREMENTAL);
fclose(fw.pFile);

FPDF_CloseDocument(doc);
```

If i do call GenerateContent (not needed i think) then the whole saved page is empty. I do use the last pdfium binary version 3764.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **uncomment** the line `FPDFPage_GenerateContent(page)`, after changing the object you need to update the object or generate the whole page.

An empty page after `FPDFPage_GenerateContent` is a **bug** already **fixed** in last builds.